# How to see which CPU has which processes running on it?

Tags: linux, multithreading, unix, cpu-usage

I have a multi thread c++ programming and using cpu affinity to lock different different threads into different cpus.

But how can I check which process is running on which cpu?

By "top", I can only see those processes. Like PID xxxx is running on CPU 5

THanks

Comment: `find /proc/YOUR-PROCESS-PID/task -name stat | xargs cat | awk ' { print $1, $39;}'`

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you find this information in the `proc` filesystem. For each thread, there is a file with the following name in the filesystem:

```
/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stat
```

The column 39 contains the CPU number the thread was last executed on. See the following man page for more information:

- http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

Answer (score 2):

Find the easiest solution: top, then f, then j, then enter. Now I have the core for each process with top.